# How to see which stored procedures are affected by changing schema name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am in the process of changing the schema of a couple of tables. Currently all the tables are in the dbo schema and need to be moved into a different schema.

I have run the following script ( on many tables):

```
ALTER SCHEMA client TRANSFER dbo.Companies
```

The issue I have now is that there are stored procedures that ned to be updated to use the correct table name

```
dbo.Companies -> client.Companies
```

Is there any way one can check which stored procedures need to be checked and fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a best method since this one needs some manual editing but here is what I would do.

I have a small query that lets me search stored procedure for a string.

```
SELECT     
     sysobjects.name
    ,sysobjects.id
    ,sysobjects.xtype
FROM         
    sysobjects 
INNER JOIN
    syscomments   
ON 
    sysobjects.id = syscomments.id
WHERE      
syscomments.text LIKE '%dbo.Companies%'
GROUP BY 
     sysobjects.name
   ,sysobjects.id
   ,sysobjects.xtype
order by 
    sysobjects.name
```

The query will give you the name, id and xtype of all stored procedures containing `dbo.Companies`. If you change the `WHERE`-clause to look for all the tables you moved to the other scheme you will (hopefully :) ) get a list of all stored procedures you need to update.

If you want you can probably modify the query and update the stored procedure body with `REPLACE` and have it all automated. But make sure the query gives you the correct results first. I did not use it for this use case, I simply use it to search for text in stored procedure but theoretically it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all objects that depend on dbo.companies. Please do remember that you will also need to change functions, views and other objects as well, apart from the stored procedures.

```
SELECT Db_name()                                   referencing_database_name, 
       Object_name (referencing_id)                referencing_entity_name, 
       Isnull(referenced_schema_name, 'dbo')       referenced_schema_name, 
       referenced_entity_name, 
       ao.type_desc                                referenced_entity_type, 
       Isnull(referenced_database_name, Db_name()) referenced_database_name 
FROM   sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed 
       JOIN sys.all_objects ao 
         ON sed.referenced_entity_name = ao.name  
WHERE sed.referenced_schema_name='dbo' AND sed.referenced_entity_name='Companies'
```

Answer (score 0):

following are the way can check the depedencies

Method 1: Using sp_depends

```
 sp_depends 'dbo.First'
 GO
```

Method 2: Using information_schema.routines

```
 SELECT *
 FROM information_schema.routines ISR
 WHERE CHARINDEX('dbo.First', ISR.ROUTINE_DEFINITION) > 0
 GO
```

Method 3: Using DMV sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities

```
 SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name,
 referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
 FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.First', 'OBJECT');
 GO
```